# passing a list of data from one screen to 2nd screen

Tags: json, api, flutter, parsing

I am passing a list of data that I called through API on 1st screen to 2nd screen and I am able to print all the data at once.
but now I want to use this data one by one and I don't know how to do that.... can you help?

this is the second screen -:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'Home_View.dart';




class AboutScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final data;
  AboutScreen({Key key,@required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AboutScreenState createState() => _AboutScreenState(data:data);
}

class _AboutScreenState extends State<AboutScreen> {

  var data;
  _AboutScreenState({this.data});

  int i = 0;
  


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(data.toString());   // here i am printing all data

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [


          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 150, bottom: 40),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Card(
                  elevation: 25,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(65),
                  ),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    child: Icon(Icons.insert_emoticon_outlined, size: 100,),
                    radius: 80,
                    foregroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),


          Text(
            '${data[0][i.toString()]}', // here i wanted to get data individually but it's showing error
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              letterSpacing: 2.5,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),



          SizedBox(height: 30,),
          Text(
            'Version 2.2',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              letterSpacing: 2.5,
            ),
          ),



          SizedBox(height: 30,),
          Text(
            'Developed By  Black Console',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              letterSpacing: 2.5,
            ),
          ),



          SizedBox(height: 40,),

          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
            elevation: 16,
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => homeView()
              ));
            },
          ),



        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

below is the data that I am getting as a list -:

```
I/flutter ( 4689): {alternateno: [7845659877, 9865358577], coachaddress: [anand vihar, delhi, delhi, Gautam Budha nagar, noida], coachemail: [bct@gmail.com, SSG@gmail.com], coachid: [1, 2], coachname: [BCT Coaching, SSG Coaching], primary_number: [9865328899, 9898557898], userid: [1, 1]}
```

can you guide me please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data variable seems to be a Map, not a list, so you can access its values like this:

```
data['alternateno'][i]
```

Comment: @palak No problem!